# How to make a scrollable absolute element be visible outside of parent

Tags: html, css

I have an items container that is vertically scrollable, but not horizontally. To one of the items I attach a small absolute positioned item (black box), that should move along (stick to the blue box) the items when scrolling up or down:

[image]

Then I would also like the content of that black box to overflow outside of the parent container, that is without making the container horizontally scrollable. At the moment, most of the black box just disappears because of `overflow: hidden`

Theoretically `position: fixed` has this behavior, but it won't move along with the items - it won't stick to the upper blue box when scrolling down.

This is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">

  </div>

  <div class="item">
  </div>

  <div class="item">
       <div class="sticky-item">
     
     </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
  </div>

  <div class="item">
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  background-color: green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.item {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 120px;
  width: 170px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.sticky-item {
  background-color: black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
}
```

Code on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/twy7g56f/1/

Please note: in the current demo the black box is already moving along the blue box beside it, this is working fine already. But it still does not overflow outside of the container.

Comment: When the blue box scrolls out of view, what do you want the black box to do? Shoul that also get hidden once it crosses the top/bottom?

Comment: @OmarSiddiqui yes that's fine thank you

Comment: Are you expecting the black element to go over the scrollbar - because I can't see a way to do that. How important is it that the scrollbar is up against the green? And what if container was made wider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a small snippet that does what you need. `.outer-container` is a wrapper element that will hold the sticky item.

In the last line of the JS section, there's an offset value of -7.5px. This can be modified as per your final version. For some reason, neither parentBCR.y nor parentBCR.top were giving the exact values and the sticky element was always slightly below where it should be. So this was a small manual alteration to fix the positioning.

```js
// Select the sticky item
const stickyItem = document.querySelector('.sticky-item')
// Get the parent from the sticky item
const parent = stickyItem.parentNode
// Find out what the index of the parent item was. Once we begin scrolling and move the sticky item to its new location, we'll need a way to attach it to the parent's top, without actually modifying the parent
const itemsList = document.querySelectorAll('.item')
let parentIndex
for (let i = 0; i < itemsList.length; i++) {
  if (parent === itemsList[i]) {
    parentIndex = i
    break
  }
}
const container = document.querySelector('.container')
const outerContainer = container.parentElement
// Add an event listener that checks if the container is being scrolled
container.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  // Select the parent at its new location at each point of the scroll
  const scrollingParent = document.querySelectorAll('.item')[parentIndex]
  if (scrollingParent) {
    // Calculate the position of the parent element while the scrolling occurs
    let parentBCR = scrollingParent.getBoundingClientRect()
    // If the scroll has just begun, we need to move the sticky element to the outer container
    if (parent.contains(stickyItem)) {
      parent.remove(stickyItem)
      outerContainer.appendChild(stickyItem)
    }
    // Calculate the new positions for the sticky element during scroll
    stickyItem.style.position = 'absolute'
    stickyItem.style.left = container.offsetWidth + 'px'
    stickyItem.style.top = parentBCR.y - 7.5 + 'px'
  }
})
```

```css
.outer-container {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 250px;
  height: 80vh;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  background-color: lightpink;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.item {
  background-color: navy;
  height: 120px;
  width: 170px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.sticky-item {
  background-color: black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="sticky-item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```